# How I can implement feedback logic for my UWP app on Xbox?

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox

I want implement feedback logic for Xbox like feedback hub on pc. But I can`t use feedback hub on Xbox.

> Feedback Hub is available only on devices that run version 10.0.14271
> or later of a Windows 10 OS that is based on the desktop and mobile
> device families. We recommend that you show a feedback control in your
> app only if the Feedback Hub is available on the user's device. The
> code in this topic demonstrates how to do this.

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/launch-feedback-hub-from-your-app*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can implement feedback logic for my UWP app on Xbox?

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/launch-feedback-hub-from-your-app),  Feedback Hub is not support for Xbox, if you want to send feedback for your app, in general, you could launch the mail app with feedback mail line and ask user post the issue.

And the other way is make custom feedback ui in your app, such as title textbox, description textbox, and attach file list. And then [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient#post-json-data-over-http) this to the your own server with [httpclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient).

Comment: Is Xbox have default mail client?

Comment: Yep, UWP [mail](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/mail-and-calendar/9wzdncrfhvqm?activetab=pivot:regionofsystemrequirementstab) app can work in Xbox.